# WhatsApp Web: how to send a video so that it is playable within WhatsApp?

Tags: video, attachment, whatsapp

When I try to send a video from a WhatsApp Web, running on Windows 10 or Linux, the video file gets attached as a file and says "Preview not available":

[image: "Preview not available" screenshot]

In order to watch such a video, it has to be saved to a filesystem and then played with a video player app.

How do I send a video from WhatsApp Web, so that it is playable within WhatsApp?

Comment: Upload it to YouTube or store it on your phone.

Comment: MP4 is technically not a file format, it’s a container. What is the codec?

Comment: You need to attach it as a Photo/video. When you click  the paperclip like button, it shows four options. The bottommost button is the Photo/video button. attach the file using that button

Comment: @desbest "MP4 is technically not a file format, it’s a container. What is the codec?" — No idea. Does it matter? Is there a codec that will be played natively by WhatsApp web? Can I convert any video to that codec?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg "You need to attach it as a Photo/video." — That's what I'm doing. It still attaches as a file with no preview.

Comment: Of course it matters. In the 2000s online video was only served in the codecs of Windows Media Video, Real Video and Quicktime Video. But you don't see that any more online, do you? Try using a video with a H264 or H265 codec.

Comment: I haven't been using ancient codecs, of course. I've been using modern codecs such as VP9 and AV1 — the ones that most web videos are encoded with and WhatsApp does not support them for some reason. Using H.264 worked, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WhatsApp uses the H.264/AVC codec internally.

Other modern codecs such as VP9 and AV1 won't work, and WhatsApp Web is unable to convert them.

The free [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr) app can be used to convert a video. Simply open a video file in it, on the Video tab choose the H.264 codec and convert, then load the resulting video into WhatsApp Web.